# what permission PAT needs to access https://analytics.dev.azure.com/ExtensionTestVee/TestProjectNOBR/_odata/v2.0//WorkItemSnapshot? API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

I used [https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{orgname}/{ProjectName}/_odata/v2.0/WorkItemSnapshot](https://analytics.dev.azure.com/%7Borgname%7D/%7BProjectName%7D/_odata/v2.0/WorkItemSnapshot) REST API to fetch the active bug counts for past 60 days for the project in Azure devops. On using the custom scoped PAT to invoke the above API it threw unauthorized exception. Could you please tell me what permissions do I need to grant for PAT to access the workItemssnapshot API.

Comment: Hi @VeenaKP, How are things going? Have you checked with the suggestion in my answer? Is it helpful to you? Please try it, and any progress, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 0):

To use [**OData API**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/extend-analytics/odata-api-version?view=azure-devops) to query work items in a project, you should have the following permissions at least:

1. On organization, your access level should be **`Basic`**.

[image]

2. In project, you should be a member of the project, and at least have **Readers** permissions. Make sure the permission **`View analytics`** is **`Allow`** for you.

[image]

3. For your personal access token (PAT), it should have the scopes **`Analytics(Read)`** and **`Work Items(Read)`**.

[image]